# how to add an empty (or default) Selection to font_formats and fontsize_formats?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

in the configuration of tinyMCE I define some font selection:

```
font_formats: "Calibri=calibri,sans-serif; Arial=arial,sans-serif; Times New Roman=times new roman,sans-serif",
fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
```

now the user can mark some text and assign a special font or a special fontsize to the marked text. 
I would like the user to be able to undo this again. That means, later the user should be able to mark 
this text again and to assign "no special font" or "no special fontsize" to the marked text. 
But in the selection of font and fontsize there is no empty item and no "default"- item.

How can I add this to these font-select-boxes?

(I use tinyMCE 4.1.10)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Clear Formatting toolbar button by adding this to the toolbar in your init:

```
toolbar: '... | removeformat | ...'
```

...this will add a button that will clear formatting from the selected text (including formatting added via the two options you reference).

Comment: thanks, it is not exactly what I wanted because it also removes other formattings like bold etc., but it is a good workaround!

Comment: The only other thing I could recommend is to build your own plugin that removes just those elements that you want to remove.  You can look at any of the existing plugins to see how they implement themselves.  You can always copy an existing plugin as a starting point and then tweak it to meet your needs.